# how to call static method inside fragement class in android?

Tags: android

```
public static void edit(String vid, String vnames, String rowid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Fragment fragment = new AddVendor();
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("vendorid", vid);
        bundle.putString("rowid", rowid);
        bundle.putBoolean("main", true);
        Log.e("2", "" + vid);
        Log.e("22", "" + rowid);
        Log.e("33", "" + vnames);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        // FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, CommonUtil.CLASS_NAME)
                .commit();
        //add();
    }
```

The fragment manager shows static method not supported error. How to call fragement?

Answer (score 0):

> how to call static method inside fragment class in android?

You can do it by adding one more argument in `edit` method of type `FragmentManager` :

```
public static void edit(String vid, String vnames, 
                     String rowid,FragmentManager fragmentManager) { 
       // use fragmentManager for transaction
     ....
}
```